# Astyanax getAll() for more than 100 entities breaks

Tags: cassandra, astyanax

I am using Astyanax 1.56.42 and facing the problem that when calling defaultEntityManager.getAll() on a columnFamily with more than 100 entities, the following exception is thrown: "Failed to fetch all entites".

The entityManager is instantiated like this:

```
entityManager = new DefaultEntityManager.Builder<T, UUID>()
   .withEntityType(typeClass)
   .withKeyspace(keyspace)
   .withColumnFamily(columnFamily)
   .build();
```

How can I fetch more than 100 datasets using getAll?

Thanks in advance!
Choesang

Answer (score 0):

Don't.  Denormalize to get what you need back in a single resultset instead.  See the resources here: http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/DataModel

Comment: I didn't really understand why you point to Denormalization.  We can definitely fetch all the data set through CQL "SELECT * FROM TABLE" but that way we get the tombstones as well. We wanted to have only active data and if possible to stick with Astyanax.